# Why do some commands use []s, some use {}s, and some use both?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I find it confusing to remember which commands take `{}` arguments, and which ones take `[]` arguments. Is there a rule-of-thumb or semantic difference between these two? If so, what? (Because they seem to serve the same purpose to me.)

Answer (score 19):

To elaborate a bit on Joel's answer, there are a few additional points. Both Knuth's plain TeX and LaTeX use `{` and `}` as grouping tokens. They are then used to delimit mandatory argument, for example

```
\section{A section title}
```

LaTeX then uses `[` and `]` to indicate optional arguments, so for example

```
\section[Short title]{A section title}
```

The idea is that some information is not always needed: if the short title is the same as the full one, there is no need to give it twice.

This convention is no 'hard wired' into TeX: it is possible to alter the approach used. For example, ConTeXt uses `{` and `}` for mandatory arguments which will be typeset and for grouping, for example

```
\quotation{Damit ich dich besser {\em sehen} kann!}
```

On the other hand, it uses `[` and `]` for arguments which are settings, and therefore will not be typeset

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]
```

Comment: I thought Context used [] for non-typeset parameters (e.g., key-value lists) and {} for typeset text.  Certainly there are Context macros that accept variable numbers of [] arguments.

Comment: @Charles Stewart: you might consider adding that comment as an answer. (The question is not tagged `latex`.)

Comment: @Charles: I'd not been aware of the distinction in ConTeXt, but I see you are right and have altered the answer accordingly.

Comment: Aha! I've always wondered on the distinction ConTeXt makes there. Now that I know what it is, it's actually rather sensible.

Comment: N.B. of course LaTeX uses {} for grouping as well.

Comment: Okay, then why not just change the number of `{}` s for the optional arguments? For example `\genfrac` uses all `{}`s, but has you leave options blank when you don't want them. Or is that just because the AMS packages are by different people? +1

Comment: Again, as I said in my answer, it has to do with how the command in question is defined, and further it has to do with how optional arguments get parsed and how they are dealt with when they are not supplied (default values) etc. Look into \providecommand to see what I mean.

Answer (score 14):

Typically `{}` are required arguments while `[]` are optional ones. Read more about that wherever you learn to define commands, for example [here](http://www.uz.ac.zw/science/maths/latex/ltx-18.html). When confused, it probably is `{}`. Are there some cases that seem especially odd? Note that TikZ really don't count as they are parsed totally differently (though with similar mnemonics).